# Meteor ReferenceError Buffer is not defined

Tags: node.js, meteor

I'm running Meteor 1.4.2.3 and after adding some code that deals with files  I get a reference error saying "Buffer" is not defined.

The error is in util.js

`exports.isPrimitive = isPrimitive;                                                                                   exports.isBuffer = Buffer.isBuffer;`

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
    at util.js (modules.js:29525)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js:343)
    at require (modules-runtime.js:238)
    at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor-node-stubs.node_modules.readable-stream.lib._stream_readable.js (modules.js:25209)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js:343)
    at require (modules-runtime.js:238)
    at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor-node-stubs.node_modules.readable-stream.readable.js (modules.js:25144)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js:343)
    at require (modules-runtime.js:238)
    at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor-node-stubs.node_modules.stream-browserify.index.js (modules.js:24653)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js:343)
    at require (modules-runtime.js:238)
    at meteorInstall.node_modules.gm.index.js (modules.js:21644)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js:343)
    at require (modules-runtime.js:238)
    at meteorInstall.both.collections.files.collection.js (app.js:2317)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js:343)
    at require (modules-runtime.js:238)
    at app.js:2583
```

What is the dependency for Buffer ? am I missing a package?

Comment: if your using buffer npm ? please import buffer

Comment: it's a dependency that uses buffer.

Comment: I had a similar error when running test with Meteor. I've added a breakpoint and traced whole call stack down to the bottom and figured out that it was npm package enzyme's fault. Updating the package solved the issue for me

Answer (score 2):

[`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) is a builtin class in Node.js and doesn't exist in browsers. If there is a separate browser compatible version of the dependency try using that one instead. If not, there is a package in NPM called [`buffer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer) that can be used as a polyfill in browsers, React Native and other non-Node.js environments.

```
import Buffer from 'buffer';

if (typeof this.Buffer === 'undefined') {
  this.Buffer = Buffer.Buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this code on Startup worked for me

```
 global.Buffer = function() {}
 global.Buffer.isBuffer = () => false
```

Complete Code looks like this

```
Meteor.startup(()=> {
  global.Buffer = function() {}
  global.Buffer.isBuffer = () => false
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
});
```